# Overflow hidden not working for absolutely positioned elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate the google's ripple effect in jquery + css.

It simply append a circular div inside buttons or divs, and when I click on the container, it applies a scale() animation to the circle.

I apply to the container (the button) the "ripple" class with position:relative and overflow:hidden, while on the circular div position:absolute

At the moment it works well for buttons, but for divs the overflow is not respected and the circle flows outside it.

```
button, .button {
    padding:0.8em 1em;
    border:none;
    background:#09F;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:0.5em;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ripple {
    display:inline;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);
}


.effetto_ripple {
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    transform:scale(0) translateZ(0);
}

.effetto_ripple.animato {
    animation:ripple 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity:0.9;
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(2.5);
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

This is the complete working code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvXKgz

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if you add some styles to the div to make it look like a real button, it works like you want. See [new codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpvbbB). So... if someone can come up with an explanation for this solution, feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow is not settalbe on inline elements, change .ripple to inline-block.  This will keep it inline, but you will be able to style it like a block element.

Comment: Oh, that's a good one, that explains what I discovered by mistake while experimenting. But [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) is the formal definition that says overflow doesn't work on inline elements.